# Reordering of text and attachment in Outlook Email

Tags: vba, outlook

I am creating an email from a macro (Excel file Macro) and am trying to make the attachment be sandwiched by text. Using the following code the attachment is added after the signature, I would like for it to have body, file, signature

```
Set olMailItem = olApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(EmailFilePath)
With olMailItem
    'search and replace subject for "KW ##" to the kw from "Key Metrics" tab
    .Subject = Replace(.Subject, "KW ##", KW)
    .Attachments.Add ("H:\QA\QA Mgmt\Presentations\" & reports(r).filename)
    .Body = .Body & GetSignature(emailTemplatePath & "EmailSignature.txt")
    .Display
End With
```

`EmailFilePath` is a path to an msg file with an existing body and reciepients. Is there a way I can force the signature to be added after the attached file?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The attachments can be placed inside of the body only when the "bodyformat" of the email is set to "Rich Text"

You can do this by implementing the following line of code into your function:

```
.BodyFormat = olFormatRichText ' 3 also works
```

Implementation

```
Set olMailItem = olApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(EmailFilePath)
With olMailItem
    ' **** Add this line vvvv ****
    .BodyFormat = olFormatRichText ' 3 also works

    'search and replace subject for "KW ##" to the kw from "Key Metrics" tab
    .Subject = Replace(.Subject, "KW ##", KW)
    .Attachments.Add ("H:\QA\QA Mgmt\Presentations\" & reports(r).filename)
    .Body = .Body & GetSignature(emailTemplatePath & "EmailSignature.txt")
    .Display
End With
```

---

Also, the 3rd parameter of the ".Attachments.Add" is "Position" and it is 0 by default but this number represents which character within the body that the attachment will be located. If your number is greater than the total amount of characters it will automatically be placed at the end. If your number is 1 it will be placed at the beginning.

This should work fine, just change the number of the position parameter

```
    .Attachments.Add Source:="H:\QA\QA Mgmt\Presentations\" & reports(r).filename, Position:=100
```

More about Outlook Attachments: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869553(v=office.15).aspx